# Springboot websocket give 404 error in postman

Tags: spring-boot, websocket

I am writing a chatroom service by springboot websocket.And i want to build multiple chatrooms for the clients base on the url.But it fail when testing postman with 404 not found

My controller :

```
@Controller
public class ChatroomController {
    private final ChatroomService chatroomService;
    private final SimpMessageSendingOperations messagingTemplate;

    public ChatroomController(ChatroomService chatroomService, SimpMessageSendingOperations messagingTemplate) {
        this.chatroomService = chatroomService;
        this.messagingTemplate = messagingTemplate;
    }
    //send chat
    @MessageMapping("/chat/{roomId}/sendMessage")
    public ChatMessage sendMessage(@DestinationVariable String roomId, @Payload ChatMessage chatMessage) {
        return chatroomService.sendMessage(roomId,chatMessage);
    }
```

My service:

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class ChatroomService {
    private final ChatroomRepository chatroomRepository;
    private final SimpMessageSendingOperations messagingTemplate;

    public ChatroomService(ChatroomRepository chatroomRepository, SimpMessageSendingOperations messagingTemplate) {
        this.chatroomRepository = chatroomRepository;
        this.messagingTemplate = messagingTemplate;
    }


    public ChatMessage sendMessage(String roomId, ChatMessage chatMessage) {
        //check chatroom is existed
        chatMessage.setDateTime(Instant.now());
        chatMessage.setOrder_id(roomId);
        messagingTemplate.convertAndSend(format("/channel/%s", roomId), chatMessage);
        ChatMessage savedchat=chatroomRepository.save(chatMessage);
        return savedchat;
    }
```

My config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebsocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    @Override       //register the endpoint
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws").withSockJS();
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws");

        //sockJs is for setting the STOMP =>send  message to who(subscribe)
    }

    @Override   //control  with "/app"  can access
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/Chatroom");
        // '/topic' is access the broker
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/channel");
    }
```

When i test with: `ws://localhost:8084/ws/chat/12/sendMessage`, it give the 404 error, but when i test with `ws://localhost:8084/ws`, it connected.Is there any problem on my url?[image]

Error :

```
Invalid SockJS path '/chat/12' - required to have 3 path segments"
```

Answer (score 0):

try configuring your application to run on a different port by adding this to your application.properties

server.port = 8081